# How do you say "creepy"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If you really think about it, some magical guy entering your house through the chimney in the middle of the night is kind of creepy. But how do you say *creepy* in Esperanto?

Answer (score 9):

I think *timetiga* is fine. Dictionaries give things like *tremiga* and *harstariga*. Here are some ideas:

- *koboldeca, diableca, fantomeca* — goblinish, devilish, ghostly
- *harstariga, (tim)tremiga* — hair-raising, shiver-inducing
- *maltrankviliga* — causing unease
- *perturbanta* — disturbing (usually literally)
- *misa* — wrong, out-of-kilter
- *antaŭsentiga* — causing a feeling in advance (usually apprehension)
- *mava; maveska, mavŝajna* — evil; with the trappings of evil
- *ŝteleca, ŝteleska* — stealthy
- *minaca, misaŭgura* — threatening, ill-omened

Comment: I like a lot of those suggestions :-). But some of them seem more spooky than creepy (tricky distinction, I know)...